# Can promises be relayed in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I have the following requirement,I have three asynchronous function async1(),async2(),ascync3() which all return promises
Now I would call one function and serially execute async1,async2,async3 respectively and I want to print the resolved promise returned after async3

this is my main function

```
testPromiseSerially = function() {
  return new promise(function(resolve,reject) {
   async1().
   then(function(result1) {
    return async2(result1)
   })
   .then(function(result2){
     return async3(result2)
   })
   .catch(function(err) {
     return reject(err) 
   }
 })
}
```

This is my async3 function

```
async3 = function(params) {
 return new promise(function(resolve,reject) {
   return resolve("solved")
})
}
```

and async1 and async2 are also similar to async3

If I execute this code

```
testPromiseSerially.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
})
.catch(function (err) {
 console.log(err) 
})
```

testPromiseSerially is getting called but it's not entering 'then' or 'catch'
block.Is promise returned by async3 not relayed back to testpromiseSerially()?
How do I see the result from async3?
 I know that if I extend my code like adding

```
.then(function(result) {
  return resolve(result)
})
```

after async3(result) then I would be able to see the result. But I have chain of functions which depend on promise returned by other functions, so how do I handle that?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that your `testPromiseSerially` code is never calling `resolve`. So the promise it returns is never resolved.

Since what it's testing *already* has promises, there's no need for you to create a new one. Every call to `then` produces a new promise, so just use that.

Additionally, this:

```
.then(function(result1) {
    return async2(result1);
})
```

is more complicated/verbose than you need, it can be just:

```
.then(async2)
```

And the same for the `.catch`.

So:

```
let testPromiseSerially = function() {
  return async1()
      .then(async2)
      .then(async3);
};
```

[Example using JavaScript's native promises on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=let%20testPromiseSerially%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20async1()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(async2)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(async3)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0AtestPromiseSerially()%0A%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Result%3A%20%22%20%2B%20result)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.catch(err%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.error(%22Error%3A%20%22%20%2B%20err)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0Afunction%20async1(val)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22async1%3A%20val%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20val)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(1)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20async2(val)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22async2%3A%20val%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20val)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(2)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20async3(val)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(%22async3%3A%20val%20%3D%20%22%20%2B%20val)%3B%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(3)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in this case async2() depends on the result of async1() so I was using the code  .then(function(result1) {
    return async2(result1);
})  . if I use  the same code as you mentioned above will async2() be called with result from async1()?

Comment: @Shakthi: Yes, for the same reason `.then(function(result1) { })` is called with the result of `async1`. In both cases, you're passing a function reference into `then`, and in both cases, the promise will call the function you passed with the promise's settled value. I've updated the code in the Babel REPL example to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use async https://github.com/caolan/async. It is be better for your case. Look at the waterfall function.

From the documentation

```
waterfall(tasks, [callback])

Runs the tasks array of functions in series, each passing their results to the next in the array. However, if any of the tasks pass an error to their own callback, the next function is not executed, and the main callback is immediately called with the error.
```